# Solid and Responsive in an wrapper which has an Responsive width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on an Responsive app and I need the search bar some parts with a responsive width and some not(like the search icon).

I tried doing it like this

```css
.wrapper{
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    border-bottom:solid 5px red;
}
.solid{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
}
.responsiv{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="solid"></div>
    <div class="responsiv"></div>    
</div>
```

But what I want it to look like is this but responsive.

```css
.wrapperWant{
    width:912px;
    height:auto;
    border-bottom:solid 5px red;
}
.solidWant{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
}
.responsivWant{
    float:left;
    width:862px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
}


.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperWant">
    <div class="solidWant"></div>
    <div class="responsivWant"></div>    
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper{
    width:80%;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom:solid 5px red;
    margin-left:50px;
}
.solid{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
    margin-left:-50px;
  border-bottom:solid 5px red;
}
.responsiv{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    float:left;
}
   .clear
   {
width:0; height:0; clear:both;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="solid"></div>
    <div class="responsiv"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>   
</div>
```